# trying to join my computers in a more efficient way

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, automation, rendering, join

i know there have several answers about how to link 2 computers together so they can share processing power. this seems to be way beyond what i need and i was hoping someone with more hardware and networking know how could shed some light on what it would take to realize my goal.

i am a computer graphics artist and often work from home for freelance clients so i have relatively powerful home computers. i would like to set up my home network in a way where i could be working on a shot in Nuke or Maya or Lightwave, or whatever i'm using at the moment, get that shot to a point where i want to render it, and then send it from the machine i'm on to the idle machine next to it so that the second computer does the rendering while the original is still free for me to continue working. 
from what i understand this should not be too difficult to achieve given that i have the same software on both computers and im asking it to preform a task that is very fragment-able since it should attack the processes one frame at a time.

both the computers are running on windows 7 and have i7 quad cores processors, 24 gigs of ram and gen force gtx 660 and 480 graphics cards. in case knowing any of those specs helps.

so far what i have been doing is saving the scenes that i want to render on the first computer, then opening them in the software on the second computer and setting up the render perimeters and rendering them. then just jumping back onto the original computer (all by physically moving between boxes). is this the best and most efficient way to do what i want or can anyone out there think of a better way for me  to set up this process so that it involves less manual movement between machines, and eliminates some of the redundancies in this process? my ideal outcome will be similar to what happens at studios where when i am ready to render my work i just submit it to the render farm which pools all the idle computers to render certain batches of frames which i specify when submitting. i know this set up requires a server which i don't have at home and am under the impression that it is too expensive and overkill for my own setup.

thanks for the help.

Comment: If your software supports this, it can automatically combine the power of your machines by doing distributed rendering.

Comment: You could look into some scripting software that scans a folder and see if a file is placed there. If so, move that file out of the folder (so it stops doing the script) and then controls your software to load your file and proceed with the rendering.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to manually move between the machines, why not put the work project into a shared folder then remote desktop into the other machine. This way you don't have to move from your original PC, just log into the other and open it up and render. I suggest you use:

Remote desktop connection (built into windows)

or

Teamviewer: http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/

If you have a little computer knowledge with IP addresses, you can use remote desktop connection. If you have no idea what that is, or just want an easier option, then just use team viewer, which gives you a custom login.

I hope this helps!

Comment: that sounds like exactly what i am trying to do. thank you. ill let you know how it works for me.
might be a few weeks since im still wrapping up a studio project at the moment. but i really appreciate the idea. only foreseeable issue is that all the files and everything must be in the shared folder so ill have to use a dynamic path for things like nuke. but again that is minor and you seem to have solved my issue.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help! Another way you can make sharing the folder a little easier is to buy a network-attached storage device, from amazon, BestBuy, Newegg or somewhere like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions.

**First**, I would share your files between the two (and more) computers using Dropbox. For large files, in the dozens and  hundreds of megabytes and larger, Dropbox is faster than a network share. It achieves this speed by how it detects and only sends changed chunks of files instead of the whole file every time.  (Also, be sure to enable syncing over LAN in the Dropbox settings.)

The other benefit is that using a network share is extremely slow (compared to a local HD) to read and save to while editing your files. The Dropbox folder is just another (local) directory.

The only potential downside is that you might have to close out of the file from your app in order for Dropbox to start syncing it. But, never mind, you'd have to do that for a network share too.

Note also that other sync tools such as OneDrive, Google Drive, Amazon, Box, Syncplicity, Oak, and other sync tools send the whole file everytime it is changed. So ease of use would be there, versus a network share, but the speed/performance  benefit would not be as good. If anyone has updated details on the others, please share, because I haven't checked in a few years on the features of the other tools; they may have added that.

**Second**, check out one of the virtual keyboard and mouse applications available. This software allows you to use one keyboard and mouse on multiple computers through the network. For instance, when you move your mouse to the edge of your screen it jumps to the screen of the other computer. And, now the keyboard and mouse input will be sent to the other computer. It is a life-saver!

I've been using such an app for over ten years by the name of [Desktop Rover](http://www.neslosoftware.com). It appears the developer may have closed up, but there are a couple others I've tried recently. The others are [Mouse Without Borders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460) from Microsoft and [Multiplicity](http://edgerunner.com/multiplicity) from EdgeRunner. Both seem to work fine. There is a small fee for Multiplicity, while Microsoft's is free.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to pay then i would recommend

Deadline 7.2
http://www.thinkboxsoftware.com/

It's what we use for send jobs to our render farm

You setup one machine as a slave and submit jobs to it through Maya, Nuke,3ds max,  Or any editing software really.

It's relatively easy to setup as well.

You can use the machine you work on as your server once it can communicate with your rendering machine your good, all you need to do is install a repository.

To test communication just Ping your other machine.